# Select with dynamic list of options with TeaVM Flavour

Tags: html-select, teavm, teavm-flavour

I am trying to set up a `select` dropdown menu, using TeaVM Flavour HTML templates.

While the doc mentions how to do it with a static list of options, it doesn't show how to handle a dynamic list of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `html:value`, which applies both to `<input>` tags as well as `<option>` tags:

```
<select name="mySelect" html:bidir-value="myResult">
    <std:foreach var="myOption" in="myList">
        <option html:value="myOption">
            <html:text value="myOption"/>
        </option>
    </std:foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: This answer appeared in [Low Quality Posts Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22951329), can you please add some explanation to your answer to avoid treating it as low quality?

Comment: Hello it seems you know TeaVM/Flavour, would you mind checking if you can share some ideas to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812435/passing-a-variable-to-a-function-in-a-foreach-loop