# Passing a variable to a function in a foreach loop

Tags: java, teavm, teavm-flavour

I want to ask how variable in `std:foreach` is handled?
I have this scenario that the same object is passed to a function regardless it it not the one that should be passed:

```html
<std:foreach var="property" in="properties">
  <button onclick="unhide('collapse-primitive')"/>
  <span class="hidden" id="collapse-primitive">
    <ul class="">
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'String')">String</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Boolean')">Boolean</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Integer')">Integer</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Long')">Long</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Double')">Double</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Set')">Set</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'List')">List</li>
      <li event:async-click="setItemPropertyType(property, 'Map')">Map</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</std:foreach>
```

This code aboves generates a span for each item in the properties List, the problem is the function `setItemPropertyType` always gets the first item, whereas this is a loop so meaning the object passed for each `setItemPropertyType` method in the span should be different. Pardon if my explanation is not sufficient, but the code itself is quite self-explanatory.

The question now is, why the same object is passed to the method regardless user clicks a `li` in a different `span`?

I also suspect it is because of the `id="collapse-primitive"` here what is causing this weird behaviour. However, I do not know how to test it without and id because I don't know how to do this in Flavour, meaning how to inject the span in the code when the button in clicked, there is the id to just "hide" it or "show" it with CSS. And okay, this is another question.

So the summary of my questions are:

1. Why std:foreach pass the same (first) variable in every function in
   a event:async-click
2. How do you inject a span or any div element for that matter on
   button click even or what is the Flavour's way of doing this?

Comment: I will try to help you. I need more details to understand what you are trying to achieve. First thing: can you please say what values you expect to be in the "properties" list, and then add to your question the HTML code that you would want Flavour to produce for you? That way we can understand whether you want 3 spans with 8 options each, or you want just 1 span with 8 options

Comment: Second, indeed you have a problem with "id". "id" is supposed to be unique at any given time. Meaning in an HTML page, at any given time there should be only one element with a given "id". The solution in Flavour is the following: 1) create a component that you would call something like "UnhideableList". 2) that component should be passed a "property". 3) That component should maintain a "hidden" boolean member. 4) Your foreach loop should create an UnhideableList component, passing it each "property" 5) Your "UnhideableList" component should have a button and your "span" (though why a span?)

Comment: Second continued: 6) Your unhideable list component's button should change the value of the "hidden" boolean member 7) Your span's "class" attribute should be replaced by "attr:class=buttonClass" 8) Your unhideable list component should have a method "getButtonClass()", that returns "hidden" if the "hidden" member is true, otherwise an empty string 9) your css should specify that any element with the class ".hidden" should have "display: none" (or whatever way you want to do it)

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew thanks for your explanation, indeed the question was quite incomplete and was hard to answer.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew I think the better approach is to create a component on-the-fly. See my answer below.

Comment: @Fireburn You're welcome. I don't know whether you have found your answer, but in any case can you please add the details that I asked for to your question, so that future readers can understand the problem you were asking about?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this is to create something like a Dropdown component that it can render itself to the DOM through HTML wrapper.

In TeaVM this can be solved with:

```java
public interface DropdownContent {
  void setDelegate(DropdownDelegate delegate);
}
```

This content can be anything HTML and expressed concretely as such:

```java
@BindTemplate("templates/views/custom-dropdown-content.html")
public class CustomDropdownContent implements DropdownContent {
}
```

with this HTML template:

```html
<span>
   <ul>
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
     <li>Item3</li>    
   </ul>
</span>
```

And obviously, other concrete implementation can be done with any HTML template.

Now, this is still just a content it must be shown to the DOM through some static method that can help build a component UI *on-the-fly*:

```java
public void showDropdown(MouseEvent event) {
    HTMLElement element = (HTMLElement) event.getTarget();
    DropdownContent content = new CustomDropdownContent();
    Dropdown.show(content, element);
}
```

The HTML `element` here is optional if the rendering can be done anywhere in the DOM, if that's the case a typical DOM injection inside the `Dropdown.show()` method can be implemented:

```java
document.getBody().appendChild(dropdownComponent.wrapper);
dropdownComponent.component = Templates.bind(dropdownComponent, dropdownComponent.wrapper);
```

This code above is not needed if you want to wrap the component from something that was clicked by the user, etc.

Now, for the the Dropdown itself, it can be implemented like this:

```java
@BindElement(name = "dropdown")
@BindTemplate("templates/components/dropdown.html")
public class Dropdown {

  private static HTMLDocument document = HTMLDocument.current();
  private Fragment content;
  private Component component;
  private HTMLElement wrapper;

  public Dropdown(Fragment content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public Fragment getContent() {
    return content;
  }

  public void setContent(Fragment content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public static void show(DropdownContent content, HTMLElement wrapper) {
    Dropdown dropdown = new Dropdown(Templates.create(content));
    dropdown.wrapper = wrapper;
    dropdown.component = Templates.bind(dropdown, dropdown.wrapper);
  }
}
```

With a very simple HTML template:

```html
<div>
  <std:insert fragment="content"/>
</div>
```

Finally, it can be used from a widget for example:

```java
@BindElement(name = "simple-form")
@BindTemplate("templates/components/form.html")
public class FormComponent extends AbstractWidget {
    public void showDropdown(MouseEvent event) {
        HTMLElement element = (HTMLElement) event.getTarget();
        DropdownContent content = new CustomDropdownContent();
        Dropdown.show(content, element);
    }
}
```

**form.html**

```html
<std:foreach var="property" in="properties">
  <button event:click="e -> showDropdown(e)"/>
</std:foreach>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to help people use TeaVM. Unfortunately, I struggle to see what benefit in this way of doing compensates the very high complexity added by its structure. Please tell me what I am missing, but after looking at this answer, I feel like this "way of doing" is not taking advantage of Flavour's ability to separate markup and logic, Flavour's ability to take care of rendering things without you having to take advantage of it, which are more generally the core features that any web framework offers. This "way of doing" seems also very confusing to me

Comment: I think this "way of doing" is also bad practice: why go back and forth between code and templates, whereas the goal of templates and a web framework is to not manually render things in code, only to pass them in things that are no longer real templates? What the question seems to want to achieve can easily be done with components that simply display things based on a condition. I see absolutely no need to call any static method of "Templates", or to create any static method for that matter

Comment: Again, I thank you for your time and effort, but I think this answer does more harm than good. It points people to a very bad way of structuring web framework code. Let me know if I am missing anything, and I would be happy to expand if you need some explanations or clarifications

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew perhaps you can also post an answer as such we can see if what you say is better?

Comment: Absolutely, I plan on doing so as soon as the question is clarified, as I asked the person who asked it

Comment: in the meantime feel free to answer my comments. As I mentioned, I might be missing something, and I'd be happy to learn

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew this answer solved exactly what I needed to do, may I ask what is the better approach you are referring to? I would like to know if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Fireburn as I mentioned above, I would love to propose another approach, but for that I would need you to clarify your question, as I indicated previously in a comment on it. I need to know what HTML you would like as output, for a given arbitrary set of "properties"

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew I think the question was clear "How do you inject a span or any div element for that matter on button click", that means you click a button then a div is injected into the DOM, that's exactly what I showed. You can post an answer and the OP can just comment on it.

Comment: Good for you if the question is clear to you. It is not to me. By the way your interpretation of the question seems biased to me. I have already asked several times for the person who asked the question to clarify what HTML they want as output. I am beginning to get tired to repeat it. So either they clarify, or I stop responding to this discussion.